# maxscript slider, read value

Tags: rendering, maxscript

I have two sliders and I need use his value in Rendering...

Definition:

```
slider maximum  "xxxx" orient:#horizontal  type:#integer range:[0,10,10]
slider minimum  "xxxx" orient:#horizontal  type:#integer range:[0,10,0]
```

Use:

```
myanim = render camera:$Camera001 fromframe:minimum.val*30 toframe:maximum.val*30 outputfile:myoutput
```

I need use values from sliders... I try .val, .value but compilers say"its undefined".

Thanks for answers

---

I solved it, its:

```
myanim = render camera:$Camera001 fromframe:(minimum.value*30) toframe:(maximum.value*30) outputfile:myoutput
```